# Chromium navigation stalls in specific cases when using request interception with Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, chromium, puppeteer

I'm currently running Puppeteer with Chromium in headfull mode and request interception enabled. I'm having an issue with the `page` not successfully navigating in some cases. The progress indicator just sits there spinning and an attached debugger sees no activity. It seems like it only happens when the page navigation is triggered by Javascript, but I'm not certain, yet.

One key place this happens is with Google's 2fa prompt. When I hit "Yes" on my phone to allow a login it begins navigating, but goes nowhere.

I'm aware that this will happen if `request.continue()` is not called. To avoid that I'm calling `request.continue()` immediately after request interception. For some reason, though, it does not always seem to function as expected.

The project source code is available at https://github.com/bgshacklett/flogin/blob/master/flogin.js

Comment: The code does not have Google 2FA, so cannot provide much on that issue. If you update your question with more code, I will update my answer and cut the chit-chat. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about when you call the `interceptedRequest.continue();` after this block?

```
if (interceptedRequest.url() === samlUrl) {
      onBeforeRequestEvent(interceptedRequest);
}
interceptedRequest.continue();
```

Though it seems it will be same since both are just async promises.

Specially this line, `When I hit "Yes" on my phone to allow a login it begins navigating, but goes nowhere.`, sometimes google 2FA takes a bit long time to finish even though you pressed YES on your phone.

And finally, the culprit seems to be this line,

```
await page.goto(new URL(authUrl).href);
await page.waitForRequest(samlUrl);
```

How can you be sure the request happens after you go to the page? waitForRequest will halt the execution until a request happens. If you are sure both are going to happen but not sure which one will happen first, then you can use the good old `Promise.all`

```
await Promise.all([
 page.waitForRequest(samlUrl), 
 page.goto(new URL(authUrl).href)
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to version 1.6.2 of Puppeteer appears to have fixed the problem for me.